# How can I remove front-end Edit button from side menus?

Tags: joomla-4.x, menu

Since upgrading to Joomla 4 (currently 4.1.5, but also occurs in a test site with 4.2.2) an Edit button has appeared above each menu in the front-end sidebar. Previously in 3.10.10 the Edit option only appeared above Articles.

How can I remove the Edit option from menus? I've searched for an answer but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3):

In `System -> Global Configuration -> Site -> Frontend Editing` you have the choice of:

- Modules & Menus
- Modules
- None

Comment: Thanks Neil. It was set to Modules, so I changed it to None and that has fixed the problem. Articles can still be edited but not menus. It doesn't seem entirely intuitive to say None but it does the trick.